# DragQueryFile doesn't recognize Hiragana Characters

Tags: c++, windows, unicode

I am trying to add support for Hiragana characters in a drag and drop interface.

```
//This works but replaces Hiragana with ?! 
string Buffer;
Buffer.resize(DragQueryFileA(hDrop, uFile, NULL, MAX_PATH));
cout << DragQueryFileA(hDrop, uFile, &Buffer[0], MAX_PATH) << ' ';
cout << Buffer;

//This works but but if I drop a file with Hiragana it turns it to whitespaces and will no longer load files
wstring wBuffer;
wBuffer.resize(DragQueryFileW(hDrop, uFile, NULL, MAX_PATH));
cout << DragQueryFileW(hDrop, uFile, &wBuffer[0], MAX_PATH) << ' ';
wcout << wBuffer;
```

I have tried using windows messages via WM_DROPFILES
and tried to use OLE+Shell with via IDropTarget

both work perfectly with single/multiple files dropped just not with the Hiragana.

//DragQueryFileA
C:/Test/20.ポジティブに行こう!.txt
becomes
C:/Test/20.?????????????????.txt

DragQueryFileW
turns hiragana to whitespace and never works again

I believe I am already using unicode...

i started off using DragQueryFile vs DragQueryFileW/DragQueryFileA but it seems to have same results

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by *I believe I am already using unicode*.

Comment: Hiragana can't fit in an ANSI string, that is why the `A` function does not work, you must use the `W` function. What do you mean it "turns hiragana to whitespace"? I seriously doubt it does that. Please provide an example of that.

Comment: On a side note, when calling `DragQueryFile(A|W)` with a NULL buffer, you should be passing in a buffer size of 0. And when you pass in a non-NULL buffer, you must pass in the *actual* buffer size, not an *assumed* buffer size. IOW, change `MAX_PATH` to 0 on the first call, and change it to `wBuffer.size()+1` on the second call

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by I believe I am already using unicode. – john 


Visual Studio:
Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults->Character Set->Use Unicode Character Set

Comment: @koomsie: What exactly is your issue? Is the issue that the string doesn't contain the dragged filenames properly, or that you cannot print them out to the console correctly?

Comment: Original File is:
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Music\20. ポジティブに行こう!.mp3
```
wstring wBuffer;
           wBuffer.resize( DragQueryFileW(hDrop, uFile, NULL, 0));
           cout << DragQueryFileW(hDrop, uFile, &wBuffer[0], wBuffer.size()+1) << ' ';
           wcout << wBuffer << endl;
           wcout << L"wBuffer.size() " << wBuffer.size() << endl;
```
C:\Users\MyName\Desktop\Music\20.

edit:  It looks like the problem might be with wcout not showing hiragana because it shows up correctly when i step through and look at it in memory just not wcout to the console.

Comment: It looks like it was assigning to the string correctly just whiting out the Hiragana characters in the console.
Researching how to do that now.  Thanks for everyone's help.

Comment: Try `::MessageBox(0,wBuffer.c_str(),0,0);` for testing the output, or use `OutputDebugString` if you have Visual Studio. To print Asian characters on the console, try changing the console font.